# magento 2.4 extending 3rd party module js file without overriding it

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, extend

I have a 3rd party module installed in app/code/ that has a js file injected to the product page via the frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml script tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/filename.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

I need to customize that js file so I've copied the file into my theme folder (`app/design/frontend/MyThemeFoler/MyThemeName/Vendor_Module/web/js/filename.js`), made all the changes needed, tested it and my changes work.

But my changes are very small (just 3 lines) while the js file is very long and involves a lot of code and methods that I don't need to touch. So I wondered if there was a way to extend the file instead of overriding in order to avoid to copy the whole file but only the method that I need to change.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to apply your changes via mixin.
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/mixins/

You can either add your code to be called before/after the original code or even replace the related method completely with your own.
The remaining code stays the same.

Small example:
I had an issue with Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha causing js errors. To avoid those errors, I added a mixin to apply my fix.

**app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha': {
            '<VENDOR>_<MODULE>/js/recaptcha-fix': true
        }
    },
}
```

};

**_/js/recaptcha-fix.js**

```
define(function() {
    'use strict';
    return function(target) {
        return target.extend({
            initCaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }
                return this._super(); // calls the original method
            },

            getIsInvisibleRecaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }
                return this._super(); // calls the original method
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Wherever the related js component is used in Magento, your mixin is automatically applied.